# Is < intentionally ignored in Javascript RegExp as an assertion (as JSLint suggests)?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, jslint

I ran JSLint on some inherited code, and received the following:

```
Problem at line 24 character 36: Unexpected '\'.

content = content.replace(/\<a href=/g, '<a target="blank" href=');
```

I've been Googling for a while and found [this](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/152) which suggests that I don't have to escape less thans in a Javascript replace.

```
HTML += '<div class="articleBody">' 
    + this.myData.record[0][0][5].replace(/<\/?a[^>]*>/gi,'') + '</div>';
```

But my standard regExp intro would suggest [they do](http://zez.org/article/articleprint/11/), as do some [other random sites](http://www.ninjavspenguin.com/regexp.html), that last even talking specifically about Javascript (though its own examples suggest JSLink is right).

> The next assertion characters match at the beginning and end of a
>   word, they are:
>
> < and >

Though Mozilla's pages ([replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)) don't say it *does* do assertions with < & >, I've been unable to find a place that explicitly says Javascript *intentionally* doesn't do assertions with < in its RegExp/replace method.  That is, **I haven't found anywhere that says a Javascript implementation that escapes < is *wrong*.**  And, indeed, the escaped *or unescaped* < seems to work fine.  Admittedly any escaped char that isn't reserved seems to work fine -- for example, \e === e, though \t !== t wrt replace().

Aside: I do realize that not all RegExp implementations are equal, and realize Javascript doesn't do, for example, look-behind.  But that's pretty common knowledge.  The assertions I'm having a harder time finding.

Can someone put this to bed for me?  Is there someplace to find that `It Is Written` that < is *intentionally* ignored as a marker of an assertion in Javascript RegExp and that anything to the contrary is incorrect behavior?

Comment: The only flavor I know of that treated unescaped `<` and `>` as word boundaries was the one that came with Visual Studio, but they replaced it with the ,NET flavor around the time this question was posted.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks for the clean up & note. No idea why I had the regexp-grammars tag on there, except that I was still pretty new to SO then [& must've missed the description].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLint is [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29), it tells you your code is problematic (according to the author's standard), but that does not mean your code is *semantically* wrong. People escape `<` and `>` to avoid the piece of Javascript code being interpreted as HTML, although escaping `<` in your case is useless.

It is guaranteed that, in JS Regex, `\<` is equivalent to `<`. (ECMA-262 §15.10.2, IdentityEscape). Basically, any non-alphanumerics escaped are equal to itself. (However, `\e` does not seem to be defined in the standard.) It is unrelated to assertions `(?<=…)`.

Comment: JSLint is _very_ opinionated, but often also "right" imo, so I was suspicious. I greatly appreciate the IdentityEscape text. Not sure if `If traits_inst.lookup_classname(n) returns null, then the escape is treated as an identity escape` from [here](http://tinyurl.com/7j5d2xo) says it exactly, but I think it's getting close. And there's nowhere in these standards docs that suggest < & > are used [as that regexp guide I ref'd explained](http://tinyurl.com/7uojapj). I'm assuming the [site](http://tinyurl.com/7swtess) that says < _must_ be escaped in JS _is_ wrong, and appreciate the help.

Comment: @ruffin: Don't use that [site](http://www.ninjavspenguin.com/regexp.html) as a reference to JS's regex. JS doesn't have POSIX character class, nor `\A`, `\Z`, `\<`, `\>`, nor lookbehinds (`(?<=…)`), atomic group (`(?>…)`), etc. That table seems more like a subset of Perl's syntax. And, if possible, [please don't use tinyurl if it's not necessary.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/145210).

Comment: Didn't have enough chars with full links; sorry.  Should've done two comments, I guess.  Yep, figured JS had a subset of regular expressions, but didn't know where it stopped nor how to find out definitively before telling our crew escaping wasn't necessary (or necessarily useful).  So perfect.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

here you go, found on http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

"Finally, flavors like JavaScript, Ruby and Tcl do not support lookbehind at all, even though they do support lookahead."

See from Important Notes About Lookbehind

Comment: But that doesn't explain [`<[a-zA-Z]+>`'s](http://zez.org/article/articleprint/11/) [dis]use in Javascript, does it?  Sorry if the aside was a red herring.  I **do** understand Javascript doesn't do lookbehind.  I **don't** understand that it's intentionally ignoring < & > as assertion characters in general.